Remove duplicate row from two different tables
Is there a way to remove duplicated rows that reside in two different tables by clicking one remove button. When I click on the remove button it only removes from the first table need to remove the same row in a second table as well.


$("body").on("click", "#remove", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <table id="tblUpdate1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" name="tblUpdate1">
    <tbody class="tbodyUpdate" id="tbodyUpdate1" name="tbodyUpdate1">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="tblUpdate" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" name="tblUpdate">
    <tbody class="tbodyUpdate" id="tbodyUpdate" name="tbodyUpdate">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>




It's definitely possible, first you need to determine which row is the duplicate, then remove it like you did the original row.

If both tables have the same data (as implied by the provided sample data) you can simply get the row index from the first table and use it to point to the row in the second one. Otherwise, you have to iterate all rows of the second table and compare cell texts.

yikes this works but seems very crude not sure if there is a better solution

You don't seem to have any elements with id="remove1" or name="remove1" so I'm not sure how this would work.

Get the index of the current row, then remove that row index in all the tables.


$("body").on("click", "#remove", function() {
  let index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
  $(`.table tbody tr:nth-child(${index+1})`).remove();
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <table id="tblUpdate1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" name="tblUpdate1">
    <tbody class="tbodyUpdate" id="tbodyUpdate1" name="tbodyUpdate1">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="tblUpdate" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" name="tblUpdate">
    <tbody class="tbodyUpdate" id="tbodyUpdate" name="tbodyUpdate">
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>




I modified it a bit from the original answer, this should work below but I like the other one better.
    <body>

<table id="tblUpdate1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" name="tblUpdate1">
    <tbody class="tbodyUpdate" id="tbodyUpdate1" name="tbodyUpdate1">
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="remove1" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="tblUpdate" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table" name="tblUpdate">
    <tbody class="tbodyUpdate" id="tbodyUpdate" name="tbodyUpdate">
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" name="remove1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-link remove" style="font-size: 11px; color:red;" value="- Remove" name="remove2"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    </body>


<script>

    $("body").on("click", "#remove1", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        $("[name='remove1']").closest("tr").remove();
    });

</script>

